# How to limit the maximum size of vector?

Tags: c++, memory, vector, queue, buffer

I am trying to use a limited-size buffer like a queue to put some numbers at the back until it gets to a specific size (e.g. 10) and then remove one element from front when a new element is added to the back.

I have used a vector for this purpose, but after several times of running the program (in debug mode) suddenly, I am getting heap corruption errors like:

> Critical error detected c0000374

in the middle of the run, and I think it should be related to memory issues, because the error goes away when I reduce the number of vectors.

So far I just use a vector and put the new value to it each time. For example, suppose the code is like this:

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> myvec;
int i = 0;

int main()
{
    while(True) {
        myvec.push_back(i);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I limit the size of `myvec` to 10, so that when it contains 10 elements and a new element is being added to it, the first element is removed from the memory?

Is it a good idea to use vectors here, or I should use a queue instead?

Comment: Yes it is a good idea to use a vector.  Just wrap it in your data structure so you can manage the size.

Comment: Just create a class and make a custom push method

Comment: There is no way of limiting the size of the vector directly.

Comment: You mention in a comment to an answer that you need to add at one end and remove from the other. That’s the job of `std::deque`. As for limiting the number of elements, just check how many are in the sequence before you push a new one. Write your own class with an appropriate interface and use an `std::deque` In the class to hold its data.

Comment: I ended up using @PeteBecker ' s suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this->

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

vector<int> myvec;
int i = 0;

int main()
{
   while(True) {
    if(myvec.size()==10)
    {
        myvec.pop_back();
    }
    myvec.push_back(i);
    i++;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I want to pop from the front and keep the element in the back. I want the elements to shift (all move at the same time) so that one element from front is removed from memory and the new element is added at the back of vector.

Comment: To remove from the front do: `myvec.erase(0);`

Comment: @JimRhodes will that limit the memory usage? I don't want to use more than 10 elements (integers) at each time.

Comment: Yes, once you reach 10 elements and remove one before adding another, the vector will not need to allocate any more memory. But the vector class may allocate enough space to hold more than 10 so that it doesn't have to reallocate every time an element is added. Read the documentation.

Comment: @JimRhodes — `myvec.erase(0)` will work, but each call to `erase` has to move **all** of the elements in the vector down by one. That’s a recipe for slow.

Comment: @HadiGhahremanNezhad if you want to pop front and push back, [consider using a `std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) in place of the `std::vector`. `deque` is not contiguous data and will be a little slower, but it's designed to handle the push one side and pop the other side use case.